# how can i use python to deploy proxies from the command line

Tags: python, linux, deployment, apigee

Deployment by using Python throws error:

I used Python code ( its your deploy.py) to deploy our proxy (our company proxy) into apigee platform. i read http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/content/deploying-proxies-command-line

but it throws error when i run "python api-platform-samples-master/tools/deploy.py -n apikey -u "yusuf.karatoprak@mobgen.com:Welcome@2014" -o yusufkaratoprak123 -e test -p / -d sample-proxies"

i would like to solve this situation. i added to python code it is not working. it throws me Error: name 'ZipFile' is not defined

[image]

Comment: What did you expect? Have you tried editing? What is the code throwing the error? Which Python-version do you use and which version is required? Which are the preconditions of running this command and are they all fulfilled? Please edit the question rather than commenting.

Comment: i would like to solve this situation. i added to python code it is not working. it throws me error :NameError: name 'ZipFile' is not defined

Comment: Did you import the module for ZipFile?

Comment: why do i need zipfile? i have files

Comment: You do not need it. The code needs something in the variable named ZipFile. My best guess is that this is the class that exists in the standart-library with the same name. You can either satisfy the hunger of the code to get this class or you edit the code so that it does not use it. This should then remove the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The -d flag value needs to point to the directory that contains the /apiproxy directory for the sample you want to deploy. (In your command above, it appears that you are pointing at /sample-proxies, rather than, for example, /sample-proxies/apikey

Try using the deploy scripts. There is one in each sample proxy directory. There's a also a script, /setup/deploy_all.sh if you want to deploy all sample proxies.

Make sure you update /setup/setenv.sh before running the deploy scripts.

Comment: i wont deploy all of my file

Answer (score 1):

The error is in how you are calling it from the command line. You have a space in one of the parameters you pass in, which needs to be put inside of quotes. Turn `-u yusuf karatoprak:123` into `-u "yusuf karatoprak:123"`

Fixed command line call:

```
python api-platform-samples-master/tools/deploy.py -n weatherapi -u "yusuf karatoprak:123" -o yk123 -e test -p / -d simpleProxy
```

Comment: Thanks but it throws error: import failed to with status 401

Comment: Edited: Have you modified the XML to point to your companies service? http://apigee.com/docs/app-services/content/using-samples#modifying-and-reusing-the-sample-api-proxies

Comment: No; i have a little knowledge. can you help me how to do that?

Comment: I have never used that service before actually. It looks like you should simply follow all the steps on [this page](http://apigee.com/docs/app-services/content/using-samples#downloading-the-samples), run your command again and you should be up and running.

Comment: i can use this approach but it will ask me password and username. i need one command line